# Can't pass an array from Flask to a JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, flask

Okay, I am very new to web development and JavaScript in particular. But I cannot figure out how to pass an array from a Flask function into a javascript function.

This is my **JS function**:

```js
function up(deptcity) {

        console.log('hi');

        $.ajax({
          
          url:"/returncity/?q="+deptcity, //the page containing python script
          type: "POST", //request type,
          dataType: 'json',
          data: JSON.stringify(deptcity),

          success:function updateDest(deptcity) {

            console.log('hi');
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            destination = document.getElementById('destination').value;
            var dest = '{{destsets | tojson | safe}}';
            console.log(dest)
            var select = document.getElementById("destination");
            var length = select.options.length;

            for (i = length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
              select.options[i] = null;
            }

            var len = dest.length
            
            for (i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
              document.getElementById("destination").add(new Option(dest[i]));
            }
          }
          });
```

And this is my **Flask function**:

```py
@views.route('/returncity/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def ajax_returncity():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        q = [request.get_json('data')]
        print(q)
        

        query = '''SELECT DISTINCT destination FROM Journey WHERE depart = ? ORDER BY destination ASC'''
        con = sqlite3.connect('Coach\database.db')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(query, q)
        destrows = cur.fetchall()

        query = '''SELECT DISTINCT date FROM Journey WHERE depart = ? ORDER BY date ASC'''
        con = sqlite3.connect('Coach\database.db')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(query, q)
        daterows = cur.fetchall()

        query = '''SELECT DISTINCT dtime FROM Journey WHERE depart = ? ORDER BY dtime ASC'''
        con = sqlite3.connect('Coach\database.db')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(query, q)
        dtimerows = cur.fetchall()

        cur.close()
        con.close()

        desti = []
        print(destrows)
        for i in destrows:
            for x in i:
                desti.append(str(x))
        print(desti)

        return jsonify(status = 'success', destsets = destrows)
        return render_template('home.html', user = current_user, departset = departrows, destsets = destrows, dateset = daterows, dtimeset = dtimerows)
```

The JS function is able to accept the array of my very Flask function that is a list of places in the database. However, this second one seems to be received as blank. When I have

```
'{{destsets | tojson | safe}}'
```

including **tojson** I get *"TypeError: Object of type Undefined is not JSON serializable"* as the error. Obviously, when I don't include it there is no error and the function just adds an empty option to the dropdown due to the variable being empty.

I have tried many different ways of passing the array through and I am at a loss of how to do it.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was sending a JS object through from flask. Fixed by just calling the variable and then the array within the object like so:

```js
function update(deptcity, destsets, datesets, dtimesets) {

        $.ajax({
          
          url:"/returncity/?q="+deptcity, //the page containing python script
          type: "POST", //request type,
          dataType: 'json',
          data: JSON.stringify(deptcity)
        })

        .then( function updateDest(destsets, datesets) {
          
          console.log(typeof datesets)
          var dest = destsets.destsets;
            
          var select = document.getElementById("destination");
          var length = select.options.length;

          for (i = length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            select.options[i] = null;
          }

          var len = dest.length;
          for (i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            document.getElementById("destination").add(new Option(dest[i]));
          }

        })
```